# How to mock currying function in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

method

```
 doSmth(event: EventDescriptor<T>): (data: Data<T>) => boolean {
        ...
}
```

Is there any way to mock such methods using Jasmine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, sure. Word you're looking for is "spying". More [here](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/spying_on_properties) and [here](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/default_spy_strategy) depending what exactly you want to mock (property answer or just whole method)

But in short, basic spy for your example for boolean would be:

```
it('should return true when called with valid data', () => {
    const mockEvent: EventDescriptor<string> = { ... };
    const mockDoSmth = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue((data: Data<string>) => true);

    const result = mockDoSmth(mockEvent)({ ... });

    expect(result).toBe(true);
});
```